# Residuals of Random Forest Regression (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

When using RandomForestRegressor from Sklearn, how do you get the residuals of the regression? I would like to plot out these residuals to check the linearity.

Comment: How about ``y - rf.predict(X)`` ?

Comment: @AndreasMueller: that's an answer, post it!

Comment: Oh I though there was a function for that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no function for that, as we like to keep the interface very simple.
You can just do

`y - rf.predict(X)`

Comment: how would you do it for binary classification?